Is there a way how to fix the size of textboxes in crystal report?
I want the textboxes to have the same sizes if one of the column data expanded.
see this:

as you can see the Owner and Location expanded, now what I want is the other columns should expand also. for more clean looking report

Crystal Reports doesn't handle grid layouts very well.  The trick to solving your problem is to not use borders on the fields to create the lines for the grid.  Use the Line tool instead.
Duplicate the section where the grid is printing.  Place vertical lines in the top section for the sides of each field.  Then format each vertical line and check the box for "Extend to Bottom of Section when Printing".
Then in the lower section you will place a horizontal line across the top of the section.
Getting everything to line up properly will feel clunky at first, but with some practice it gets easier.  There are also some report settings you can adjust that can be helpful.  To find the settings go to File > Options and look for "Grid Options".  Sometimes turning off snap to grid can help, or changing the grid size to a value that is easily divided into the width of the objects/fields on the report.  Just bear in mind that the Grid Options settings are global settings throughout the entire Crystal Reports application.  If you have reports that use different Grid Options, I recommend documenting it somewhere to help editing your reports later easier.
And you may also want to try using the "Size and Position" settings on the fields, lines, and other report objects that are part of the grid layout.  Being able to set the height and width and starting coordinates of objects can help place things exactly where you want them when the snap to grid won't allow it.

Thank you! will do some work around with the report

Edit: I have achieved my desired output. Thank you so much!
